# Laravel 4 Undefined Method Illuminate Http Request Request::post()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple html form and am calling a controller in the routes file, but upon submission I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()"

Stacktrace:
#1 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:205
#0 Illuminate\Exception\Handler:handleShutdown in <#unknown>:0
```

On this particular site, I have many forms and even more routes and all work except this one. I've looked again and again and again for some typo or something that might be causing it to fail, but can find nothing.

My form is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/warehouse/add_pallet" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pm-well">   
                <h2>Scan Add Pallet</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2" for="pallet_location">Location: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pallet_location" id="pallet_location">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2" for="sku">sku: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sku" id="sku">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="submit" class="pm-btn pm-btn-confirmation medium-btn" value="Add Pallet">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in my routes file I have:

```
Route::post('warehouse/add_pallet', 'PalletController@insert');
```

As a control test, I setup just a straight PHP (no Laravel or any PHP framework) test site and copied the form and changed the form action to simply point to another php script where I could echo out the request method and the post data and that worked as expected.

I'm stumped at this point. Could this be a bug? I have seen lots of other posts about problems with Symfony's Request::[methods] not working.

Comment: You haven't shown your `PalletController`, but I guess you just need to use `Input::post()` instead of `Request::post()`

Comment: I'm not even getting to the controller. and am not using Request::post(), that is being called by the framework Kaloyan. Check the error message at the top of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have called a method post() inside your controller as either Request::post() or Input::post(). You should use Input::get() instead. The keyword **get** in the Facade Input is not bound to the $_GET global array. So whether you are submitting data using GET or POST method, you should use Input::get('*key*') to retrieve them.
However to make sure that the data you are fetching is submitted through the POST method, you can use the `Request::method() == 'POST'` or `Request::isMethod('post')` surrounding your code.

Comment: Yes that was it. I was just trying to var_dump(Input::post()) and should have used Input::get() instead. I really wish Laravel's error reporting would have pointed me to my own code instead!  :P  Thanks clife.

Comment: The same to me, I was trying $data = \Input::post('data') but the correct is \Input::get('data')